# How to show the "syn_sent" socket state on Linux in realtime?

Tags: networking, netstat, ss

I want to see the state "syn_sent" of socket in realtime during the connection process
ss or netstat or any command
I have tried those commands, but all fail

```
watch netstat -tnaop|grep -i syn
ss -4 state syn
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found: this command works perfect

```
watch "ss -o state syn-sent '( dport = :https or sport = :https )'
```

this command also works fine

```
while true;do sleep 2s && netstat -napotep|grep SYN_SENT; done
```